SQL группировка, создание дублей

Добрый день, подскажите , могу ли я с помощью MYSQL 5.7 из двух записей сделать 8
то есть мне нужно продублировать записи
и сделать к примеру с первой строки
H067  S070
2      01
2      03 
2      #
2      05

на скрине это результат выборки который мне нужно еще отработать
UPDATE
вот набросал чтото примерное
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS new_table;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS new_table (
                            id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
                            name varchar(255),
                            date_start DATE NULL,
                            date_operation DATE NULL,
                            date_return DATE NULL,
                            params_1 int,
                            params_2 int,
                            params_3 int,
                            PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE `UTF8_unicode_ci`;

INSERT INTO new_table (name, date_start, date_operation, date_return, params_1, params_2, params_3)
VALUES ('название_1', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-05', '2023-05-05', 1, 1, 0),
 ('название_2', '2023-05-01', '2023-08-05', null, 1, 1, 0),
 ('название_3', '2023-06-01', '2023-09-05', '2023-05-05', 1, 1, 0),
 ('название_4', '2023-07-01', '2023-10-05', '2023-05-05', 1, 1, 0),
 ('название_5', '2023-08-01', '2023-11-05', null, 1, 1, 0),
 ('название_6', '2023-09-01', '2023-12-05', '2023-05-05', 1, 1, 0),
 ('название_7', '2023-10-01', '2024-01-05', null, 1, 1, 0),
 ('название_8', '2023-11-01', '2021-02-05', '2023-05-05', 1, 1, 0);

select
    t1.id,
    t1.H067,
       CASE WHEN params_1 = 1 AND date_return is NULL THEN '01' ELSE '#' END as 'S070_01',
       CASE WHEN params_2 = 1 AND date_operation is NOT NULL THEN '03' ELSE '#' END as 'S070_03',
       CASE WHEN params_3 = 1 AND params_2 = 1 THEN '04' ELSE '#' END as 'S070_04'

from (
         select *,
                '1' as 'H067'
         from new_table
         where date_start > '2023-09-01'
         UNION ALL
         select *,
                '2' as 'H067'
         from new_table
         where date_operation > '2023-07-01' and  date_operation < '2023-12-31'
         UNION ALL
         select *,
                '3' as 'H067'
         from new_table
         where date_return is null
     ) as t1

по итогу мне нужно 2 столбца
H067 S070

только чтобы H067 имел все условия
нюансы что new_table имеет несколько милионов записей и джоитится  также к много милионным записям

Разумеется, здесь надо переделать эту чудовищную структуру БД. Как минимум, выкинуть все эти дублирующиеся колонки с подчеркиваниями. Вы сами-то не видите весь идиотизм ситуации когда в значение колонки пишется цифра из имени колонки? И чтобы записать новое значение, приходится создавать новую колонку?

Просто спросил совета можно или нет , логику я заложил чтобы решить ту или иную задачу , пошел по этому пути поэтому и уточняю

Да все ок ) пытаюсь найти решение с группировкой думаю может есть какието хитрые условия с которыми я не сталкивался

Я и объясняю, что идти по этому пути не следует. Надо сначала прочитать букварь по организации структуры БД, а потом уже "закладывать логику".

да пока что не важно что там будет указанно 01 и 03  тут задумка в том что если не # значит это есть выполненное условие по этому полю а если есть услове то нужно сделать дубль записи чтобы дальше сумму подкинуть на это условие , согласен что решение не сильно хорошее но у меня в sql сейчас 120 строк кода , если такое не делать то думаю можно умножить на 5 , поэтому  пока что пытаюсь найти решение по такому пути

Если делать нормально, то 120 строк SQL можно будет легко поделить на 10. Но для этого надо учить основы реляционных БД и учиться формулировать задачи.

Всетаки помощь еще актуальна )

Шаблон для дублирования записей в таблице:
INSERT INTO tablename ( {список полей без поля автоинкремента} )
SELECT {список полей без поля автоинкремента}
FROM tablename 
CROSS JOIN  (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION  .. SELECT N) numbers
WHERE {дополнительные условия}

N - максимальное количество создаваемых копий.
Дополнительные условия могут ограничивать количество копий отдельных записей.
В списке выходного набора SELECT-части можно модифицировать вставляемые значения.
Если первичный ключ - не автоинкремент, следует в списке вывода SELECT формировать уникальное значение для ПК соотв. выражением.
Если количество нужных копий велико, можно CROSSJOIN-ить несколько синтетических таблиц. Также вместо синтетической таблицы чисел можно использовать рекурсивный CTE. Но не в случае MySQL 5.x, который их не поддерживает.

Мне кажется, что конкретно этому кадру нужны дубли не в таблице, а в выборке. Но не поручусь, тут может быть всё что угодно.

@Ипатьев Может быть... но тогда просто убираем INSERT-часть и используем чисто SELECT-часть запроса.

Так ему не просто продублировать, ему нужно сгруппировать этот адский винегрет. У меня такое ощущение, что он родил этакую "pivot-table наоборот" - то есть вместо нормальной структуры данных и построения из них сводной таблицы, он эту таблицу решил материализовать!

@Ипатьев Да по текущему описанию и правда мало что ясно. Подождём. Может, автор таки соберётся и выдаст свою хотелку на вменяемом техническом языке, чтобы другим понятно было. Ну а нет так нет - чай. не у нас проблема.

@Akina добавил описания, я решил вопрос другими способами но выборкой до конца не получилось решить
